# Selecting info in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i want to select all where my account exits

but am getting this error

DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
USER

ID      ACCOUNT
1       JOHN
2       JANE
3       JET
4       KAT
5       YMT


FRIENDS

ID       ACCOUNT  FRIEND   
1        JOHN      JET
2        JET       JANA
3        KAT       JOHN


NOTIC

ID       ACCOUNT
1        JOHN

SELECT count(*) FROM notic WHERE account IN (SELECT account, friend FROM friends WHERE account = 'JOHN'  OR friend = 'JOHN'
```

Comment: Change `SELECT account, friend` to just `SELECT account`.

Comment: Or maybe it should be a UNION, one query returns `account`, the other returns `friend`.

Comment: @Barmar i tried that and only returns from 1 col only yet i want to check all col in FRIENDS

Comment: i havent tried it with union kindly share with me the way i can do it in union

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the `friends` table on `notic.account = friend.account` or `notic.account = friend.friend`

Something like this

```
select count(*) from notic n join friends f on n.account = f.account || n.account = f.friend where n.account = 'JOHN';
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/780493/8) showing it working

Comment: This will multiply the count by the number of entries matched in `friends`. Try `COUNT(DISTINCT n.id)`

Comment: Also need `WHERE n.account = 'JOHN'`